# Stop the request handling after timeout in nest.js

Tags: express, nestjs

I am using the **TimeoutInteceptor** from the Nest.js [document](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#more-operators) to the handle the timeout. It works correctly and the client-side will be received a *Request Timeout* error after a set duration. However, in the Nest.js app, the request is still being handled normally.

**How to cancel the request handling after it has timed out?**

I could make it work by setting a *timedout* property in the request object. In the handler, then I would check if the property is set after every statements or function calls (or at least the expensive ones) and exit accordingly.

This is okay if I were to apply this to a single handler, but there are many handlers and it would be a mess.

Answer (score -1):

It highly depends on your handlers code and what do you want to timeout. Without more information about its processing flow and technique it is hard to determine what your issue is.

Imagine you implemented interceptor like in the documentation page you linked. Timeout is 5000.

If you have an observable based code like below:

```
public handle(): Observable<unknown> {
 return of('handled').pipe(
  delay(6000)
  tap(value => console.log(value)
 );
}
```

The console.log statement won't be called (as expected) - request handling is timed out. If you change the delay to 4000 it will be called. It works correctly and in a manner you want to achieve.

If your code is not written in the similar manner you should start from there. Is it fully observable based or promise based? Do you want to time out an async or sync code? Do you have your observable processed in a pipe() chain or do you have an dangling subscription somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.